# UnboundLocalError with a function in python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm writing a telegram bot and, to abbreviate a long instruction, I created a function (called printmsg) that contains that instruction.
In the same program I received the error in the title before, and I resolved putting the variable out of the function as a parameter of that, but now the error refers to a function when it should warn me of a variable. I really don't know how to resolve this.

This is the code, for some context:

```
# LIBRARIES
from random import *
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters



# CONSTANTS & VARIABLES
TOKEN = ''

# These variables contain different ways to reply to a user's hello
hello_counter = 0
hello_list = ['ciao :)', 'ehi', 'sciao', 'hello', 'hola', 'bonjour']
greatings_list = ['ciao', 'ehi', 'buongiorno', 'salve', 'buonasera', 'hola']

# These variable contains different ways to reply to a user's goodbye
goodbye_list = ['a dopo :)', 'sciaoo', 'adios', 'gudbai', 'ciao :)']

# This variable contains various ways to reply when the bot doesn't understand the message
eh_list = ['eh?', 'wut', 'parla una lingua comprensibile ai comuni mortali, grazie', 'si, come se avessi capito', 'ok...']




# FUNCTIONS
def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('''
    Ciao
    ''')

# This function has to choose the appropriate way to reply to the user, based on what he/she wrote
def reply(update, context, ciao_counter=0, ciao_list=ciao_list, greatings_list=greatings_list, adopo_list=adopo_list, eh_list=eh_list):
    msg = update.message.text.lower()
    match msg:
        case msg if msg in greatings_list: 
            match ciao_counter:
                case 0: 
                    printmsg(choice(ciao_list))
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 1:
                    printmsg('Mi hai già salutato, non serve che lo fai di nuovo')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 2:
                    printmsg('Mi. hai. gia. salutato.')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 3:
                    printmsg('Basta, non ti rispondo più')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case _:
                    printmsg('...')
        
        case msg if 'a dopo' in msg:
            printmsg(choice(adopo_list))
            ciao_counter = 0

        case _:
            printmsg(choice(eh_list))




    # This function serves only to shorten the instruction to send a message (this is the function that gives the error)
    def printmsg(text):
        update.message.reply_text(text)


# STARTING BOT
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, reply))
updater.start_polling()
```

The error

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/home/ricky/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 199, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/home/ricky/Scrivania/Coding/bot.py", line 37, in reply
    printmsg(choice(ciao_list))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'printmsg' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is executed in order. The definition of `printmsg()` doesn't happen until after the `match` statement, so you can't call it during `match`. You need to move it to the top of the function.

```
def reply(update, context, ciao_counter=0, ciao_list=ciao_list, greatings_list=greatings_list, adopo_list=adopo_list, eh_list=eh_list):
    # This function serves only to shorten the instruction to send a message (this is the function that gives the error)
    def printmsg(text):
        update.message.reply_text(text)

    msg = update.message.text.lower()
    match msg:
        case msg if msg in greatings_list: 
            match ciao_counter:
                case 0: 
                    printmsg(choice(ciao_list))
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 1:
                    printmsg('Mi hai già salutato, non serve che lo fai di nuovo')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 2:
                    printmsg('Mi. hai. gia. salutato.')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case 3:
                    printmsg('Basta, non ti rispondo più')
                    ciao_counter += 1
                case _:
                    printmsg('...')
        
        case msg if 'a dopo' in msg:
            printmsg(choice(adopo_list))
            ciao_counter = 0

        case _:
            printmsg(choice(eh_list))
```